# Fill the form on the website (ideally with Java) - registration to Search Engines

Tags: java, html, webforms, html-parsing, captcha

I need fill the form on the website (registration to Search Engines or free catalogs).

I programing in Java SE, but I have no experience with the fill forms on the web page with Java. I would like to Open Source program, so no commercial libraries, but only with a license from BSD to GPL.

Me idea is (may be wrong):
1) first, we need to get elements to fill:
- in the own database
- receive from the HTML Parser
2) if the captcha, and automatically decode (recognize) or offer a picture (for the code).
3) send the completed form (POST) - ideally with confirmation

I Would like to ask for advice:
a) what library to use for HTML Parser ?
b) anticaptcha or recognize library ? (like JDownloads or FRD (FreeRapid Downloader)
c) any tutorial or similar sample code to send form

Thanks in advance.
Merax

Comment: *if the captcha, and automatically decode (recognize) or offer a picture (for the code)* Captcha is kep to prevent this only

Comment: Don't bother. Seriously. The only search engine worth registering with is Google (just because it is so popular, you want to be on there first). Anywhere else that is worth while is going to pick up sites from links anyway. And, as Jigar implies, if you were allowed to make automated registrations, then there wouldn't be a CAPTCHA anyway.

Comment: I think the same thing. I am a student (web designer). Unfortunately, hard to explain to people that it is not so important. That is a few major search engines, which should not be missed. They just want to be a hundred search engines and catalogs. Why? Because other companies (web designer) are doing this and say how much it matters. This is not to say that backlinks are unimportant. I do not think I would necessarily user the anticaptcha. If the key catalog use captcha, so I prefer to do manual, because there are few important (with few steps).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion whole thing with parsing html does not have to be necessary. You may just need to prepare proper url (with all required parameters) and simply call it. To deduce how url should look like you can use firefox with HttpFox plugin.

Of course my solution does not take into consideration captchas.

Answer (score 0):

Try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).